# Edit sliding html menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, menu, sliding

I'm using a sliding menu (select/object html one), which is generated dynamically by taking data from a DB, using a jsp page.

I also have an input text field, where I can search things from the sliding menu.
I want to write the root of a word that is contained in my menu, and my menu must "resize" showing all the items with the root that I've wrote, and only those ones.

I can't use server side operations (like sending data via post) but I need to solve this client side (because I need this result immediately).

Can I maybe solve this problem only with an onclick event applied to a button? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UKseV/8/

As it is not possible to hide an `<option>` with `display:none` (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UKseV/ -style is added correctly, but it does not work), I clone select object to store initial options as they will be removed from  initial object. And later I'm using that cloned object to filter options and add those that match my condition to initial object. Here is a code:

HTML:

```
<select multiple id="testSelect">
<option>test</option>
<option>temp</option>
<option>cast</option>
<option>dest</option>
<option>inst</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="" onkeyup="searhSelect(this)" />​
```

`searhSelect` function will be called on each key press (when user release a key actually) and will filter `#testSelect` object.

JS:

```
var optionsList;
function searhSelect(el) {
    var select = document.getElementById('testSelect');
    if(!optionsList) {        
        optionsList = select.cloneNode(true);  //copy select to a variable for future use      
    }
    select.innerHTML = "";//remove all options.

    for(var i =0; i < optionsList.options.length; i++) {
        var opt = optionsList.options[i];
        if((opt.innerText || opt.textContent).indexOf(el.value) != -1) {
            select.appendChild(opt.cloneNode(true));
        } 
    }
}
```

​

Comment: Thank you for your great replay. At The moment i actually don't know how the text I type will filter my list. I did like you said, but when i type, The list is cleared, and no options appear when i type correct content. What did i wrong?

Comment: @abierto - if you want to get some help - show your code. Have you copy pasted both HTML and JS? Where is JS code located? Were there some modifications? How can I know that all?

Comment: You are right, but now i solved it, thank you! ;) too bad that textContent doesn't work on IE8 and below, only innerText and innerHTML work.. And they are too slow, because my list has too many elements, and it takes like 30 seconds to update...